# How to get element from MySQL table using a singular attribute in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, mysql-connector

So let's say I have the following table for a student:

```
+----+------------+-----------+---------------------+----------+------------+
| first_name | last_name | ID     | Birthday        | Grade    | Periods    |
+----+------------+-----------+---------------------+----------+------------+
|  John      | Doe       | 123456 | 1/1/2004        | 11       | 7          | 
+----+------------+-----------+---------------------+----------+------------+
```

How could I get the ResultSet for just that one student by just using their ID for example?
Could the query be `SELECT ID(123456) FROM Students"` or something along those lines? I found some answers online as to how I could loop through all the Students for example and print out that data or do something else with it, but not how to get the data for a singular element in the table based on one attribute.

In short, I just want to be able to get all the data on a student from just their ID number.

Comment: `String sql = "SELECT * FROM Students WHERE ID = 123456;";`. I'm sure students don't share ID's in your database. If you want to get a resultSet for all the Students in grade 11 then you would use: `"SELECT * FROM Students WHERE Grade = 11;";`. You will want to also use prepared statements so as to avoid injection.

Comment: @DevilsHnd  Thanks for your help, I completely forgot to ask about that. So right now for the ID's I'm just generating a random number. Is there a way to check if any student already has the ID 123456 for example?

Comment: Yes, it would go something like this: `String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS SameNumber FROM Students WHERE ID = 123456;"`. The temp Field named `SameNumber` will hold the number of students that contain that ID number.

Comment: When generating a new ID number, get the actual new number from the database Students table based on the largest Student ID value added to that table and then add 1 to that, for example in MySQL I believe it is something like this: `"SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Students;"`. Just add 1 (or whatever) to the returned result.